# Python equivalent of the MATLAB psf2otf function

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing

Is there a Python equivalent to the MATLAB psf2otf function?

[This is a link to the MATLAB function's documentation.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/psf2otf.html)

**EDIT:**

A document found online with more information on this:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.04187

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phypher library has functions that achieve the same thing:

https://github.com/aboucaud/pypher/blob/master/pypher/pypher.py